# Showing there is an infinity of prime numbers of the form $12k+11$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, provability

I want to prove there is an infinite number of prime of the form $12k+11$. I worked hard to make the first part of my solution but I don't know how to do with the second part.
First : I suppose there is a finite number of prime of the form $12k+11$, let'S call them $p_1, p_2,..., p_r$.

Let $N=12(p_1p_2...p_r)-1$.

$N$ is not divible by any of the prime in the list $(p_1, p_2,...,p_r)$ because $n+1=12(p_1p_2...p_r)$ and two consecutives numbers can't both be divible by $p_1$. The same argument goes for $p_2, p_3,...,p_r$. Now, we know that $N$ is divisible by a prime that isn't in the list, or $N$ is a new prime of the form $12k+11$ that is not in the list. We can see that $N$ has a form of $12k+11$ because $N=12((p_1p_2...p_r)-1)+11$ and $N\equiv{-1}\equiv{11}\mod{12}$.

Next: Now I have to prove that $N$ is divisible by a prime of the form $12k+11$ but I don't know how. I found that all the prime numbers can be written with the form $12k+5$, $12k+7$ and $12k+11$ except $2,3$ and $13$.

Can you help me with that last part and tell me if the first part is correct?

Comment: This is a good idea, but unfortunately it won't work, because $N$ may factor (for example) as $pq$ where $p \equiv 5 \pmod {12}$ and $q \equiv 7 \pmod {12}$.

Comment: Also your last claim isn't quite correct:  all primes other than 2 and 3 have one of the forms $12k+1, 12k+5, 12k+7,$ or $12k+11$.  There are infinitely many primes of the first form:  13, 37, 61, 73, etc.

Comment: You might be aware of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, which is the general theorem covering statements like this.  Dirichlet's theorem requires a lot of machinery to prove, but a few special cases can be done in the spirit of Euclid's proof.  Keith Conrad has worked these out in detail (https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/squaresandinfmanyprimes.pdf); your case is Theorem 3.12.  It requires using quadratic reciprocity to find a clever choice of $N$ that can't be divisible by primes of the form $12k+5$ or $12k+7$.

Comment: Related:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717358/infinitude-of-primes-that-are-11-bmod-12

Comment: Yes, I have seen this post, but it did not went the same way I wanted to go. Maybe I did wrong on all of my solution. So i'll take a better look at KingLogic post.